# Ruby 2.7.5 PKCS7 decrypt without a certificate

Tags: ruby, openssl, pkcs#7

Starting in ruby 2.7.5, the `OpenSSL::PKCS7#verify` method requires a cert. How are we expected to decrypt data when there is no cert?

Here's the change in the underlying source for this method, comparing [2.7.4](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.4/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKCS7.html#method-i-decrypt) to [2.7.5](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.5/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKCS7.html#method-i-decrypt):

```c
/* 2.7.4 */
x509 = NIL_P(cert) ? NULL : GetX509CertPtr(cert); /* NO NEED TO DUP */
/* 2.7.5 */
x509 = GetX509CertPtr(cert); /* NO NEED TO DUP */
```

Indeed, supplying `nil` for this arg works in 2.7.4, but in 2.7.5, it produces the error `wrong argument type nil (expected OpenSSL/X509).`

Comment: Oh, Your right. This seems to be the pull request that fixes it in the ruby openssl gem. https://github.com/ruby/openssl/pull/183. Not sure if you can even try that but its clear this was never patched into 2.7.5